# add title when exporting grid to excel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use the following code to export a datatable to excel

Is there a way to add a title to the excel sheet??

Here is the code I use to generate the excel sheet.

```
enter code here
    public void export2(DataTable dt)
    {
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid grid = 
                           new System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid();
        grid.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
        grid.DataSource = dt;
        grid.DataBind();
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\Reports\\Report.xls"))
        {
            using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                grid.RenderControl(hw);
            }
        }
    }
```

The output from this looks like this

```
Name    Employee ID 
abc         123 
def         456
ghi         789 
jkl         987
mno         654
```

is it possible to get the output as shown below??

```
Employee Report

Name    Employee ID 
abc         123 
def         456
ghi         789 
jkl         987
mno         654
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to add the title(e.g. as Label) and the GridView/DataGrid  to an UserControl wrapped in an ASP.NET Panel or DIV with appropriate CSS. Then you can [render](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.usercontrol.rendercontrol.aspx) the whole `UserControl` instead of only the Grid.

Another would be to create real excel files instead of html-tables for example with [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/releases/view/42439).

Answer (score 4):

```
public void export2(DataTable dt) 
{
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid grid = 
                       new System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid();
    grid.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
    grid.DataSource = dt;
    grid.DataBind();
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\Reports\\Report.xls"))
    {
        using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            **hw.Write("Employee Report");**
            **hw.Write("<br>");**
            grid.RenderControl(hw);                
        }
    }
}
```